# How to display the average of the votes of a rating field from a form made with webform (D8)?

Tags: 8, webforms

I've made a rating form using the webform module.
I'm looking for a way to display the average result of the votes on the node.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Webform Analysis](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_analysis) module.

> This module is used to obtain statistics on the results of form
>   submissions.

Comment: This module doesn't have any documentation... I have an error when I click on the tab 'analysis'. Could you explain me how to statistics on the results on form submission on a node ?

Comment: The maintainer of the Webform Analysis module is very responsive and you should post a ticket in their issue queue.